# MEF giving CompositionException

Tags: mef

I am new to MEF and I am trying this following program.

The class library whose dll I am making has following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;

namespace MefTestsCore
{
    [Export (typeof(MefTestsCore.IFace))]
    public class CoreClass1 : IFace
    {
        public String getName()
        {
            return "CoreClass1";
        }
    }

    interface IFace
    {
        String getName();
    }
}
```

The program which wants to access the dll has following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using MefTestsCore;

namespace MefTests
{

    class Program
    {
        [Import (typeof(MefTestsCore.IFace), AllowRecomposition=true)]
        public IFace iFaceObj;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.Method();
        }

        public void Method()
        {
            DirectoryCatalog catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(@"C:\Users\username");
            CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
            container.ComposeParts(this);
            Console.WriteLine(iFaceObj.getName());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I have the MEFLibrary.dll (dll containing MefTestsCore namespace, the first part of above code) at C:\Users\username. When I run the program, it throws CompositionException with following details

```
The composition produced a single composition error. 

The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.

1) The export 'MefTestsCore.CoreClass1 (ContractName="MefTestsCore.IFace")' is not assignable to type 'MefTestsCore.IFace'.

Resulting in: Cannot set import 'MefTests.Program.iFaceObj (ContractName="MefTestsCore.IFace")' on part 'MefTests.Program'.
Element: MefTests.Program.iFaceObj (ContractName="MefTestsCore.IFace") -->  MefTests.Program
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test program you are using MefTestsCore. So I assume you referenced that assembly from your test program. But then you also load a copy from c:\Users\username. Now they types don't match because they come from different assemblies.

You have to put the interface into it's own assembly so that you then can reference it from your program and from MefTestsCore.